# Scripts wont run

Tags: scripts

Going through tutorial on linuxcommand.org. Every script I write, even copy paste, won't run. Here is what I did:

```
gedit test_script.html
```

in gedit:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for filename in "$@"; do
    result=
    if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
        result="$filename is a regular file"
    else
        if [ -d "$filename" ]; then
            result="$filename is a directory"
        fi
    fi
    if [ -w "$filename" ]; then
        result="$result and it is writable"
    else
        result="$result and it is not writable"
    fi
    echo "$result"
done
```

Then I go to command line: `chmod 777 test_script.html`

Then I execute: `./test_script.html`

and it does nothing? It doesn't send an error, just goes to next command prompt?

I am sure I am doing something stupid?

Comment: You aren't giving it any arguments (positional parameters) to loop over ...

Comment: minor nitpicking... `.html` as a script?! Gah!

Comment: Just try for example: `./test_script.html *`

Comment: please change the file extension to `.sh`

Comment: Just as a side question, why did you give it the name `.html`? It's a shell script written in bash, nothing to do with html. It doesn't actually need an extension, but if you give it one, `.sh` is the standard. Although the name will not have any affect on how it is executed when you specify what does it.

Comment: Try inserting an `echo "Running..."` at the beginning of the program just after the `#!/bin/bash` so that we are sure that the program is actually not running rather than just not getting into the for loop.

Comment: haha. I see your point with the .html. It is just the script that is used in the tutorial @ http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0130.php. Thanks for all the help! you guys rock, and yes I got it to work. I changed it to .sh b/c I like to be exact! thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script is looking for a positional argument. So you need to run the command like this:

`jtoscarson:~/Downloads$ bash test.sh ./
./ is a directory and it is writable`

Comment: If this answered your question please mark this as answered. And no problem.